# "Export" x509 certificate in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl, x509

I'm communicating with an API that has the following directions:

1. Install the issued x509 certificate onto the client server.
2. Export the x509 certificate using the supplied password and default Machine Key Set into memory.
3. Base64 encode the exported bytes of the x509 certificate.
4. Add ‘X509Certificate’ as an HTTP header and set its value to the result of step 3.

Step 1 and 4 are easy, but I have no idea on 2 or or the 'export' portion of 3. I have tried Googling for some time and I'm not sure exactly where to even really start.

Would someone point me in the right direction on how to "export" a certificate with "machine key set"?

Here is what I have so far

```
raw_data = File.read('cert.pfx')
pkcs = OpenSSL::PKCS12.new(raw_data, 'password')
cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(pkcs.certificate.to_pem)
```

Here is equivalent .NET code:

```
public string GetBase64Cert(string certificateThumbprint)
 {
 using (X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine))
 {
 store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
 var foundCertificates = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, certificateThumbprint, false);
 if (foundCertificates.Count != 1)
 {
 return null;
 }
 var certByteArray = foundCertificates[0].Export(X509ContentType.Cert);
 store.Close();
 return Convert.ToBase64String(certByteArray);
 }
}
```

And equivalent PHP code:

```
public function setx509($x509file) {
  $cert = openssl_x509_parse($x509file);
  $base64cert = base64_encode($cert);
  return $base64cert;
}
```

Comment: Is Private key supposed to be included? (directions are resembling PKCS12, with export to binary DER and Base64-encoding) Please provide more details on how that api is going to use the certificate

Comment: Unfortunately this is literally the only documentation I can find in their 100+ page PDF, and on their entire site. I'll be able to email them tomorrow so I will ask tomorrow specifically about the private key being included. This will be used when sending API requests to a payment processing platform from a non-PCI compliant server to authenticate with their API. They require credentials + IP whitelisting + x509 in header to authenticate properly.

Comment: Where do you get the certificate and in which format? For authentication process must be something like "create a keypair, keep private key private, upload CSR and get final certificate signed by them" (certificate at this step contains only public key, sometimes later certificate and its private key encrypted with password are written in p12 format). Are they implementing some custom kind of SSL Client certificate mechanism?

Comment: @Vasfed they have sent me a single `cert.pfx` file which has binary data inside it, as well as a password

Comment: @Vasfed I added PHP and .NET code (these were the only code samples they had)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
pkcs = OpenSSL::PKCS12.new(File.read('cert.pfx'), 'password')
str = Base64.urlsafe_encode64(pkcs.certificate.to_der)
```

Probably also `str.gsub(/=+$/, '')` to cut off padding

Comment: It doesn't work (it gives invalid certificate error), but I think it's something on their end because your answer produces an output that exactly looks like a decoded64 string that I told them to give me from their dev environment. when i decoded64 i get the exact binary output as what you put above... i think they dont have the certificate 'enabled' for my account or something. Thank you for your help, ill mark it success for now

Comment: @Tallboy also try with `strict_encode64` and no/with padding (`=`s at the end for some inputs), they may be using string comparison over base64